# Loop through parsed json string in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a complicated structure of returned by an URL in JSON format, i have got the reponse which I can view through var_dump, Now I have this reponse,

```
{
  "groups": [],
  "total_pages": 1,
  "spots": [
    {
      "address": {
        "region": "TX",
        "locality": "Austin"
      },
      "name": "Dirty Bill's",
      "checkins_count": 646,
      "_image_url_200": "http://static.gowalla.com/categories/28-b0d41920d32839ce1ecd6641e5fc2c87-200.png",
      "image_url": "http://static.gowalla.com/categories/28-78c9b4d7d239784df49dc932f64a3519-100.png",
      "_image_url_50": "http://static.gowalla.com/categories/28-78c9b4d7d239784df49dc932f64a3519-100.png",
      "radius_meters": 50,
      "trending_level": 0,
      "users_count": 375,
      "url": "/spots/43711",
      "checkins_url": "/checkins?spot_id=43711",
      "lng": "-97.7495040214",
      "spot_categories": [
        {
          "name": "Dive Bar",
          "url": "/categories/28"
        }
      ],
      "foursquare_id": null,
      "highlights_url": "/spots/43711/highlights",
      "items_url": "/spots/43711/items",
      "items_count": 11,
      "strict_radius": false,
      "description": "AKA the Gnome Bar. Much Warmer than Key Bar.",
      "activity_url": "/spots/43711/events",
      "lat": "30.2696322356",
      "photos_count": 23
    },
    {
      "address": {
        "region": "TX",
        "locality": "Austin"
      },
      "name": "Austin Wellness Clinic",
      "checkins_count": 1,
      "_image_url_200": "http://static.gowalla.com/categories/118-b41c2ba96f1ffe99fc23f12f0ee3b960-200.png",
      "image_url": "http://static.gowalla.com/categories/118-5f9e72162abf3dcbc0108cdbdba6a29f-100.png",
      "_image_url_50": "http://static.gowalla.com/categories/118-5f9e72162abf3dcbc0108cdbdba6a29f-100.png",
      "radius_meters": 75,
      "trending_level": 0,
      "users_count": 1,
      "url": "/spots/7360448",
      "checkins_url": "/checkins?spot_id=7360448",
      "lng": "-97.7495133877",
      "spot_categories": [
        {
          "name": "Health & Fitness",
          "url": "/categories/118"
        }
      ],
      "foursquare_id": null,
      "highlights_url": "/spots/7360448/highlights",
      "items_url": "/spots/7360448/items",
      "items_count": 0,
      "strict_radius": false,
      "description": null,
      "activity_url": "/spots/7360448/events",
      "lat": "30.2695755256",
      "photos_count": 0
    },
```

I have used json_decode($response,true) to get a parse variable, now I am not sure as to how to loop through it. Any ideas?!

**edit 1:** The spots is an array[] which has an index 0. I want to loop though each name valu pair inside the spots array

Comment: What do you want to loop through? This isn't a question of parsing.

Comment: Loop it like a regular array, because it is.

Comment: what u want to make a loop?? please write your desired array

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php or http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Do you want to convert the whole array in an flat array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$json = json_encode(
    array(
        'spots' => array(
            'bar' => 'baz',
            array(
                'quz' => 'foo',
                'bar' => 'baz'
            )
        )
    )
);

$root = json_decode( $json, true );

function read( $array ) {
    foreach( (array) $array as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_array( $value ) ) {
            read( $array );
        }
        echo "$key = $value\n";
    }
}

foreach( $root['spots'] as $spot ) {
    read( $spot );
}
```

This should give you all the information inside the spot array.

**EDIT**: Now with actually checked syntax, it works.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, sorry, missed an } for the foreach, so it appeared. Anyway, it now works.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = json_decode($response,true);

foreach($result['spots'] as $spot)
{
    echo $spot['address']['locality'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or try this one:

```
$result = json_decode($response,true);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($result));
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
        echo "<b>".$key."</b><br />".$value."<br />";
}
```

This will convert a complex associative array in a simple array for looping.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't loop through that, you'd use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) to get through it. You need to write a function that can call itself, passing different branches of that structure to itself as the arguments. [This](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1235) might help you with PHP recursion.